# Unable to delete directory

Tags: filesystems, osx, directory, rm

On my OS X host, I am having trouble deleting the directory "foo".

```
mymac:.Trashes joe$ ls
foo
mymac:.Trashes joe$ ls foo/
Ảnh011.jpg  Ảnh012.jpg  Ảnh013.jpg
mymac:.Trashes joe$ ls -l foo/
ls: Ảnh011.jpg: No such file or directory
ls: Ảnh012.jpg: No such file or directory
ls: Ảnh013.jpg: No such file or directory
mymac:.Trashes joe$ rm -rf foo/
rm: foo/: Directory not empty
mymac:.Trashes joe$ sudo rm -rf foo/
Password:
rm: foo/: Directory not empty
```

As you can see, there are some files under the directory "foo" which I can only run `ls` on; running `ls -l` returns an error. I cannot delete the individual files or the directory. Using "Empty Recycle Bin" did not work either. I have also tried 'Disk Utility' -> 'Verify Disk' and 'Repair Disk'.

Edit:
As requested, here are more info

```
mymac:.Trashes joe$ ls -del foo/
drwxrwxrwx  2 joe  staff  16384 13 May 11:19 foo/
mymac:.Trashes joe$ ls -del foo
drwxrwxrwx  2 joe  staff  16384 13 May 11:19 foo
mymac:.Trashes joe$ LC_ALL=C
mymac:.Trashes joe$ ls -ABeli foo/
total 1812
18972612676 -rwxrwxrwx  1 joe  staff  305951 13 May 11:19 Ảnh011.jpg
19123958587 -rwxrwxrwx  1 joe  staff  309745 13 May 11:19 Ảnh012.jpg
18511775654 -rwxrwxrwx  1 joe  staff  310907 13 May 11:19 Ảnh013.jpg
mymac:.Trashes joe$ find foo/
foo/
foo//Ảnh011.jpg
foo//Ảnh012.jpg
foo//Ảnh013.jpg
```

Comment: Does `cd`ing into the directory and doing something like `rm -f -- ./*` work? (I'm not sure if OSX's rm accepts the -- syntax to terminate command line processing for arguments, but don't see why it shouldn't.)

Comment: :( nope, no error, but didn't delete anything

Comment: Maybe `rm` is aliased to something. Try `/bin/rm` instead.

Comment: Other thing you can try is `find foo/ -type f -delete`.

Comment: Please run the following commands show (exactly these commands, with the same options and the same punctuation): `\ls -del foo`, `LC_ALL=C \ls -ABeli foo/`, `find foo/`. Copy-paste the output into your question.

Comment: Hi Gilles, I've just updated my post.

Comment: tried with /bin/rm too, same problem

Comment: Hi hulk, I've tried with find delete too. Got same 'No such file or directory'

Answer (score 2):

It appears that somehow you have entry names in `foo` which do not link to a valid node for a file. I'm not sure how that could happen or why `rm -rf` would not delete the entry from the directory even if it did.

But perhaps if you associate the directory entry with a valid file node it will delete? In other words, maybe this?

```
touch foo/Ảnh011.jpg
rm foo/Ảnh011.jpg
```

---

Hmmm. Does anyone else think the `//`  in the result below is, well, unexpected?

```
mymac:.Trashes joe$ find foo/
foo/
foo//Ảnh011.jpg
foo//Ảnh012.jpg
foo//Ảnh013.jpg
```

I would have expected it to be as shown below. Could the `//` (whatever it is) have been a clue to the problem?

```
foo/Ảnh011.jpg
foo/Ảnh012.jpg
foo/Ảnh013.jpg
```

Comment: Yep I've tried that, but didnt work. touch: foo/Ảnh011.jpg: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried renaming the files first? The files have a special character at the beginning "Ả". Try renaming the files first and then delete them.

Comment: Yep, tried. I got 'No such file or directory' error.

Comment: Try using `mv ?nh01?.jpg anh01?.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Replies above are good, but there's another thing you should know.

By default 'ls' (or 'ls -l') doesn't show files whose names start with a '.' (aka "dot files")

To make sure you see all files use 'ls -a'.

It is possible, although not certain that you have other files starting with a '.' in 'foo/' and that's why it is not empty.

That said, they should have been removed with '/bin/rm -rf foo' so there has to be some other issue in that dir.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the files with this command and then delete the folder.

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: If `rm -rf` isn't working, plain `rm` almost certainly won't. It might be worth trying `-delete`, however. Which you should use instead of `-exec rm` anyway.

Comment: Looks like I didn't understand the question. Sorry.